# AVAudioPlayer Freezes the UI when new sound is played

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am new to iOS and I was searching fix for this issue since morning and didn't find the solution yet, I have more than 6000 sound files online which i want to play using `AVAudioPlayer` when user click on the cell, so i implemented it in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`
like this :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [soundsArray objectAtIndex:(int)indexPath.row]];
     NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
     _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:soundData  error:NULL];
        [_audioPlayer play];
    }
```

the problem is, whenever i click on any row, the whole UI freezes till the time it takes to load the complete sound file from internet, 
for larger files , it takes longer.

I tried with `AVPlayer` and it is working fine, but I need `AVAudioPlayer` becouse it seems easy to me to work with 
`-(void)AVAudioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)Player successfully:(BOOL)flag`

thats why I want to implement it with `AVAudioPlayer`

I hope you understood my problem, 
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: to stop already playing song first is good practice you must try by stopping player before loads another song.. may works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use

```
 NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

this will block your UI.

You need to use `NSURLSession` to download data asynchronously.

Comment: ow.. i will try it now

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Comment: can you please show me the example of NSURLSession, i never used it before